# how to create vertical scroll effect for slider using js ,html,css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://www.squarespace.com/
i want to create similar sliding effect for my website 
could someone suggest how to create such kind of effect
I tried using fullpage.js but it doesnot give the same effect 
is there a plugin or js which could provide such kind of effect

Answer (score 0):

There's an extensive article about [Fancy Scrolling Sites](https://css-tricks.com/fancy-scrolling-sites/) from CSS Tricks. Have that as a start point.

There are a lot of tutorials for this. I would start something with:

- [Create a Cool Website with Fancy Scrolling Effects](http://line25.com/tutorials/create-a-cool-website-with-fancy-scrolling-effects)
- [Fancy Scrolling Sites](https://css-tricks.com/fancy-scrolling-sites/)

Considering the plug-ins, you may try out [Curtain.js](http://curtain.victorcoulon.fr/).

Comment: can this javascript could be added to bootstrap website too?

Comment: @RajatBagree Yes, I guess so!